# Using SphinxQL with SphinxSE

Tags: sphinx

Can I actually use sphinxQL with SphinxSE plugin?
Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE query='SELECT id FROM products GROUP BY region, price';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Two completely different ways of accessing sphinx.

SphinxSE under the hood uses the SphinxAPI.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE query=';select=id;index=products;groupby=attr:region,price';
```

Although I dont know if the multiple attribute group by will work.

Comment: Why oh why would they do that... SphinxSE syntax is so redundant in comparison to SphinxQL.

Comment: SphinxSE, was around before sphinxql 'invented'. It's natural later innovations can learn from earlier ones.